# Has Isaiah 14:1-2 been fulfilled?

Tags: isaiah

Berean Study Bible Isaiah 14:

> 1 For the LORD will have compassion on Jacob; once again He will choose Israel and settle them in their own land. The foreigner will join them and unite with the house of Jacob. 2The nations will escort Israel and bring it to its homeland.
>
> Then the house of Israel will possess the nations as menservants and maidservants in the LORD’s land. They will make captives of their captors and rule over their oppressors.

Has this been fulfilled?

Comment: Prophecy fulfilment questions are nearly always very opinion based. Futurists would say no, preterists would say yes. In neither case is the answer found in the exegesis of Isaiah 14. So I don't think this is on-topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider those two verses with the two verses which follow:

> "For the LORD will have mercy on Jacob, and will yet choose Israel,
> and set them in their own land: and the strangers shall be joined with
> them, and they shall cleave to the house of Jacob.  And the people
> shall take them, and bring them to their place: and the house of
> Israel shall possess them in the land of the LORD for servants and
> handmaids: *and they shall take them captives, whose captives they
> were*; and they shall rule over their oppressors.  And it shall come to
> pass in the day that the LORD shall give thee rest from thy sorrow,
> and from thy fear, and from the hard bondage wherein thou wast made to
> serve.  That thou shalt take up this proverb against the king of
> **Babylon**, and say, How hath the oppressor ceased! the golden city
> ceased!" (Isaiah 14:1-4)

The text brings out the fact that the captives would swap roles with their captors; with Babylon being explicitly mentioned.  This is also given in the future tense, indicating its fulfillment must be future to the time in which the prophecy was given.  As this is Isaiah's prophecy, it would have been given around the time of Hezekiah, king of Judah, and well before the seventy years of captivity in Babylon had begun.

The prophecy is to give hope to those who should be taken captives to Babylon that they would afterward return to their own land from the place where they had been taken as servants.  Their oppressor, Babylon, would oppress them no more after this.  This prophecy was fulfilled about 534 B.C., or shortly afterward, when the 70 years of captivity, prophesied by Isaiah (see Isaiah 22, especially vs. 17) and Jeremiah (see 2 Chronicles 36:21 & Jeremiah 25:11-12), had come to an end.

Comment: What about the second half, that Israel will possess the nations as servants?